# Intersection of affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $[0, 1]^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Suppose I have an affine subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, say given by a rank-$r$ system of $m$ equations in $n$ variables.  I'm interested in two questions:

1. Is there a straightforward way to determine whether $V$ intersects $[0,1]^n$?
2. If so, is there a straightforward way to determine the intersection?

Tags are a bit of a guess here; feel free to edit.

Comment: This answer by Shor looks useful: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/complexity-of-checking-whether-linear-equations-have-a-positive-solution

Comment: Oh, wow, that's an unpleasant state of affairs.  Thanks for the reference.